# Why is relative positioning causing space below elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` on my [homepage](http://www.nights2stay.com), not positioned, it holds the main image. On top of this main image I have a container which holds my search bar. I've positioned this container `position:relative` `top:-500px;` so that it appears over my main image.

I then have another 2 containers which come next, but if I do nothing positionally with them, they appear after a big vertical space, so I've had to `position:relative` and add a minus top to. I have to keep doing this `top:-300px` or whatever because if I don't a space appears beneath which I can't fill.

Now the next `div` down is the footer which I don't want to have to posiiton because it appears on every page. How can I get rid of the space between my featured properties and the footer?

Here's the code:

```
//no positioning
<div style="margin: 0 auto" class="slideshowWrap">
    <div class="homeslideshow slide1"> 
    </div>
    <div class="homeslideshow slide2">  
    </div>
    <div class="homeslideshow slide3">   
    </div>
</div>


//position:relative top:-500px
<div id="homecontainer">
</div>


//position:relative; top:-300px; margin-bottom:-100px;
<div id="homeBoxContainer">
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

//position:relative; top:-300px; 
<div id="homeFeaturedContainer">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused... You fix all that _blocks_ with negative `margin-top`to separate all of your stuff. I only understood that, what is really your problem over here?

Comment: Did you visit his website? His footer is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem the way you designed your containers. When you moved everything up using position:relative and top:-300 it moves everything up, but the height from your #content is still saving the space and maintaining the height.
If you want your footer links up, add the following code

```
#footer {
top: -300px;
position: relative;
}
```

that doesn't solve your problem because you still have the big height created by your odd design. You need to go back to the drawing board and redesign your container. You don't need the position:relative and moving everything up.

Comment: i dont want to add more css to my footer because it apears on every page so will screw all the other pages up...

Comment: Ideally I'd have just the first container which needs to hover over the main image position:absolute but if I do that it seems to dissappear behind the image

Comment: thanks man I think I got it working by adding a -300 to the bottom margin of the last container :)

Answer (score 0):

I generally only set top and bottom values on absolutely-positioned elements. Try this instead:

```
#homeFeaturedContainer {
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-bottom: -300px;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you in? It doesn't affect anything else in Chrome. I've used this technique several times before.